# Issues quoting exclusions for rsync in bash script

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm using a bash script to sync a web folder using rsync. I'm using an array of folders and files to exclude, and I'm having problems escaping these items for the exclude list...

my exclude list is defined like so...

```
SYNC_EXCLUSIONS=(
    '/exclude_folder_1'
    '/exclude_folder_2'
    '.git*'
    '.svn'
)
```

Then I build my exclusion string like so...

```
exclusions='';
for e in "${SYNC_EXCLUSIONS[@]}"
do
    exclusions+=" --exclude='$e'";
done
```

Then finally I execute my rsync...

```
rsync --recursive --delete $exclusions "$DEPLOYMENT_WORK_DIR/" "$DEPLOYMENT_ROOT/"
```

If I echo the command it looks perfect, and if I copy and execute it at the prompt it works correctly. However when run from the script the exclusions are ignored.

I've figured out that it will work if I remove the single quotes from around each excluded item, like so...

```
exclusions+=" --exclude=$e";
```

I'd prefer to not do that though, just in case I need to exclude folders with spaces or special characters.

Is there some way I can get this to work from the script while retaining quotes around the excluded items? I've tried all sorts of combinations of quotes and backslashes etc. and nothing I've tried works.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: BTW, using all-caps names for your own variables is bad form. See [POSIX guidelines on environment variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) (paragraph 4), specifying that variables with all-caps names are used by the shell and system, and that variables with other names can be used by applications without conflict; because shell variables share a namespace (setting a shell variable with the name of an environment variable will overwrite the latter), these conventions apply to shell variables as well.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. This is a convention I've used in various other languages, to indicate that something is intended to be constant. I didn't realise it wasn't good practice in bash. I'll change my code.

Comment: To be fair, it's a convention that isn't followed as often as it should be -- but it *is* black-letter POSIX, and keeps folks out of trouble (like inadvertently running `for PATH in */; do ...`, and having an interpreter that can no longer execute external programs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't build a string for this at all -- see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for an extensive discussion of why. Build an array.

```
exclusions=( )
for e in "${SYNC_EXCLUSIONS[@]}"; do
    exclusions+=( --exclude="$e" )
done

rsync --recursive --delete "${exclusions[@]}" "$DEPLOYMENT_WORK_DIR/" "$DEPLOYMENT_ROOT/"
```

---

...well, can't build a string at all, *unless you're going to execute it with `eval`*. Doing that in a manner that isn't prone to shell injection vulnerabilities takes care, however:

```
printf -v exclusions_str '--exclude=%q ' "${SYNC_EXCLUSIONS[@]}"
printf -v rsync_cmd 'rsync --recursive --delete %s %q %q' \
  "$exclusions_str" "$DEPLOYMENT_WORK_DIR/" "$DEPLOYMENT_ROOT/"
eval "$rsync_cmd"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.

Comment: You can create the `exclusions` array without a loop through the magic of string substitution: `exclusions=("${SYNC_EXCLUSIONS[@]/#/--exclude=}")`. This expands `SYNC_EXCLUSIONS`, but in each element 'replaces' the beginning of string ("#") with "--exclude=".