# how to keep nested BASH parameter untokenized

Tags: bash, shell

Consider this trite BASH script:

```
g1="f 2.txt"
g2="f1.txt $g1"
cp $g2
```

It fails because I passed three parameters to the `cp` command. How do I escape the `$g1` call to make it pass just two on the final line (er, make it work without passing two variables on line three)? I tried putting quotes around it with no success; it then proceeds to pass the quotes as part of the parameter, which is doubly weird.

In my real scenario I have some optional parameters that themselves take parameters. I had wanted to parse them all out at the top of the script and leave their final parsed values blank if they weren't passed in.

Comment: It is unclear. What command do you actually want to execute? Is it `cp f1.txt f\ 2.txt`

Comment: Please update your example with parameters you've mentioned. Otherwise quoting like this `g2="f1.txt '$g1' "` should work

Comment: @Vladimir: That does *not* work; quotes and escapes are parsed before variables get substituted, so by the time they're part of the command, it's too late for them to have the intended effect. I'm not sure I understand the question right, but for anything like this arrays are usually the right answer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987452/issues-quoting-exclusions-for-rsync-in-bash-script) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/360966/how-do-i-use-a-bash-variable-string-containing-quotes-in-a-command).

Comment: @GordonDavisson , I'm satisfied with your second link. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: @anubhava , yes, you understand the intention of the example code.

Comment: Relevant: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using shell arrays:

```
g1="f 2.txt"
g2=("f1.txt" "$g1")

cp "${g2[@]}"
```